# DB2 Stored Procedure Update XML column through user input

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, db2

My code works if I would pre-define the changes i want within the query but I want the user to provide his own input so that he can change any specific XML column based on user input.

My problem is it is giving me errors and it does not identify the variable NEWADD which I have declared. Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MNI_UPDATE_STUD_ADD(   in  IDNUMBER    CHAR(8),
                                    in  NEWADD      VARCHAR(50))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

LANGUAGE SQL

begin

    UPDATE XML_STUD
    SET STUDINFO = xmlquery('copy $test := $STUDINFO modify do
                            replace value of $test/Student/Address with NEWADD
                            return $test')
    WHERE IDNO = IDNUMBER;

end
```

I want that the user could input any world he want under the variable NEWADD, I have no problems with the variable IDNUMBER it is working fine my only issue the NEWADD. Is there any way to call a variable within an xmlquery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness I'm pasting here the answer provided to you [elsewhere](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1697071-store-procedure-updating-xml-column-user-input.html):

You should reference the variable in the XMLQUERY string similarly to other variables in it, `$STUDINFO` and `$test`. Use the `PASSING` clause to define that variable.

```
... xmlquery('copy $test := $STUDINFO modify do
                replace value of $test/Student/Address 
                with $foo return $test'
                passing NEWADD as "foo"
)...
```

Comment: yes thanks i already got it. but this will be added to my collection of information.